# Typing an Array with a union type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.4

I was just wondering if it is possible to type array with a union type, so that one array can contain both Apples and Oranges but nothing else.

Something like

```
var arr : (Apple|Orange)[] = [];

arr.push(apple); //ok
arr.push(orange); //ok
arr.push(1); //error
arr.push("abc"); // error
```

Needless to say, the example above does not work so this may not be possible, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
class Apple {
  appleFoo: any;
}

class Orange {
  orangeFoo: any;
}

var arr : Array<Apple|Orange> = [];

var apple = new Apple();
var orange = new Orange();

arr.push(apple); //ok
arr.push(orange); //ok
arr.push(1); //error
arr.push("abc"); // error

var something = arr[0];

if(something instanceof Apple) {
  something.appleFoo; //ok
  something.orangeFoo; //error
} else if(something instanceof Orange) {
  something.appleFoo; //error
  something.orangeFoo; //ok
}
```

Comment: the definition does not throw an error but you can not access neither properties of Apple nor Orange

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a type guard example.

Comment: That's interesting. I was doing the mistake that Apple and Orange were interfaces, not classes but then you can not type-guard for interface so you could not reach the properties. Thanks.

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek if they were interfaces rather than classes, it is still possible you'd have to do a bit more work (http://bit.ly/1Gi14Uu) - i.e. `if (arr[0].hasOwnProperty("name")) {
 var a = <Apple>arr[0];
 console.log(a.name);
}`

Comment: Awesome. I wish all this info was somewhere nicely in one place, but I understand TS is moving forward so fast ...

Comment: different techniques to make type guards: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types

Answer (score 15):

As per TS 2.3.4 is as simple as

```
let someArray: (typeA|typeB)[] = [
  new typeA(),
  new typeB()
]
```