# Array for mixed types in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have existing API that I thinking to add type to, and I have function that accept string function or object (I can use overloading for this) but it also accept array of mixed values like these.

Is it possible to have Array of strings, functions or plain objects in TypeScript? It should throw error for array with other types.

**EDIT** based on comments I added this:

```
function Terminal(interpreter: (string, object) => void, settings: object);
function Terminal(interpreter: (string | ((string, object) => void) | object)[], settings: object) {
    if (typeof interpreter == 'function') {
        interpreter("foo", {});
    } else if (interpreter instanceof Array) {
        interpreter.forEach((arg) => console.log(arg));
    }
}

Terminal(["foo", function (command, term) { }], {});
Terminal(function(command) {

}, {});
```

but got error in TypeScript playground about overload signature don't match implementation and one from invocation.

Comment: Yes, it's possible: `(string | Function | object)[]`

Comment: or `string[] | Function[] | object[]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typing an Array with a union type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29794014/typing-an-array-with-a-union-type-in-typescript)

Comment: Mixed-type arrays are generally poor design. Objects are better for this case in most cases.

Comment: @ggorlen in my case, it's not poor design, thanks for your comment completely not related to the question.

Comment: @jcubic Thanks for clarifying, but the note is primarily intended for future visitors who stumble on the question and wind up falling into an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). In most typed languages, it's not easy to create mixed-type arrays for good reason: it's an antipattern. You typically have to typecheck the array any time you need to use it, as the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50803510/6243352) shows. I'd only suggest this pattern in narrow cases, like building requests to poorly-designed APIs that you can't control.

Comment: @ggorlen so you're basically saying that using, for instance, polymorphism is poor design?

Comment: @jcubic I don't see the relationship between polymorphism and mixed-type arrays. If you have an array of elements that are polymorphic then aren't you're treating them as a single type?

Comment: @ggorlen the classic example of usage of polymorphism is a mixed type array when you iterate over an array of objects and execute a single method no matter what type the object is.

Comment: That's not what you're doing here--you're checking the type with an `if`, which seems to defeat the purpose of polymorphism.

Comment: @ggorlen but you've said that most of the time mixed type array is poor design, this is an example that you're wrong.

Comment: Yes, I said "generally", not "all of the time", and what you're doing here in this code smells like an antipattern.

Comment: @ggorlen also the code in the question is not my real code, this is a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use union type, you have to list all possible argument types in that union type. If you say

> function that accept string function or object (I can use overloading for this) but it also accept array of mixed values like these

you can define type alias for a single value that can be string, function or object

```
type SingleArg = string | object | ((string, object) => void);
```

and define a function that takes one SingleArg or array (you don't need to have any overloads)

```
function Terminal(interpreter:  SingleArg | SingleArg[], settings: object) {
    if (typeof interpreter == 'function') {
        interpreter("foo", {});
    } else if (interpreter instanceof Array) {
        interpreter.forEach((arg) => console.log(arg));
    }
}

Terminal(["foo", function (command, term) { }], {});
Terminal(function(command) {

}, {});
```

The other restriction

> It should throw error for array with other types.

is tricky because for example numbers are objects in TypeScript. To be able to disallow numbers, but not objects, you have to be more specific about the exact kind of the objects that should be accepted.