# Typescript - Using generics to extend an interface with a property of union type

Tags: typescript, generics

I have an interface like this

```
interface Test {
  values: string[] | number[] | Date[]
  // more properties
}
```

I would like to create another interface that makes the type specific. What I am trying is:

```
interface TestWithType<T extends string | number | Date> extends Test {
  values: T[];
}
```

But this fails with an error saying `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'`.

What is the correct syntax for this? If property `values` was not an array, this would work fine

```
interface Test {
  values: string | number | Date
}

interface TestWithType<T extends string | number | Date> extends Test {
  values: T;
}
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29794014/typing-an-array-with-a-union-type-in-typescript

Comment: And this too https://stackoverflow.com/a/29382420

Comment: Now I understand why this is not compiling (the generic constraint would allow me to give the array values of different types). Still not sure how to make it specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've noticed, you don't get `string[] | number[] | Date[]` by apply making an array of elements of type `string | number | Date`.  And since `(string | number | Date)[]` is wider than `string[] | number[] | Date[]`, you get a compiler error since you can't widen properties of subtypes.

@MattMcCutchen's answer gives some ways to deal with this.  Here's another way:

If you have a union like `string | number | Date` and want to programmatically turn it into a union of arrays like `string[] | number[] | Date[]`, you can use [distributive conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#distributive-conditional-types):

```
type DistributeArray<T> = T extends any ? T[] : never;
```

Then you can define `TestWithType` in terms of `DistributeArray`:

```
// no error:
interface TestWithType<T extends string | number | Date> extends Test {
  values: DistributeArray<T>;
}
```

And verify that it behaves as you expect:

```
declare const testWithString: TestWithType<string>
testWithString.values; // string[]

declare const testWithDate: TestWithType<Date>
testWithDate.values; // Date[]

declare const testWithStringOrNumber: TestWithType<string | number>
testWithStringOrNumber.values; // string[] | number[]
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

---

EDIT:

> As a related question, is there any way to forbid passing an union type to the generic? (As in requiring to only specify at most one of string, number or date)

Yeah, that's *possible*, but it requires abusing the type system in a way that makes me uncomfortable.  I'd suggest not doing that if you don't need to.  Here it is:

```
type DistributeArray<T> = T extends any ? T[] : never;
type NotAUnion<T> = [T] extends [infer U] ? U extends any ? 
  T extends U ? unknown : never : never : never
type ErrorMsg = "NO UNIONS ALLOWED, PAL"
interface TestWithType<T extends (
  unknown extends NotAUnion<T> ? string | number | Date : ErrorMsg
)> extends Test {
  values: DistributeArray<T>
}

declare const testWithString: TestWithType<string> // okay

declare const testWithDate: TestWithType<Date> // okay

declare const testWithStringOrNumber: TestWithType<string | number> // error:
// 'string | number' does not satisfy the constraint '"NO UNIONS ALLOWED, PAL"'.
```

The type `NotAUnion<T>` evaluates to `unknown` (a top type) if `T` is not a union... otherwise it evaluates to `never` (a bottom type).  Then, in `TestWithType` the type `T` is constrained to `unknown extends NotAUnion<T> ? string | number | Date : ErrorMsg`, barely skirting the rules against circular references.  If you pass a non-union as `T`, it becomes `T extends string | number | Date` as before.  If you pass a union, it becomes `T extends ErrorMsg`, a string literal type.  Since a union will never extend a string literal, it will fail...  And the error message you get will involve `ErrorMsg`, so it should hopefully be enough for a developer to realize what's happening.  It works, but it's very very sketchy stuff.  You asked for it, though.

Good luck again!

Comment: Great, this solves my problem. As a related question, is there any way to forbid passing an union type to the generic? (As in requiring to only specify at most one of string, number or date).

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions, using lookup types or conditional types:

```
enum TestType { STRING, NUMBER, DATE }
interface TestTypeMapping {
  [TestType.STRING]: string[];
  [TestType.NUMBER]: number[];
  [TestType.DATE]: Date[];
}
interface TestWithType1<T extends TestType> extends Test {
  values: TestTypeMapping[T];
}

type TypeToArrayType<T> =
  T extends string ? string[] :
  T extends number ? number[] :
  T extends Date ? Date[] :
  never[];
interface TestWithType2<T extends string | number | Date> extends Test {
  values: TypeToArrayType<T>;
}
```