# How to create a generic interface or type that accepts tow different interfaces that go under single array?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to be able to create a generic type that works with an array that accepts tow similar object but not totally equal, every thing works fine until I want to access a value that is not in both objects in this case the gender property.

```js
// React state logic 
interface Client {
  name: string;
  clientId: string;
  weekId: string;
  gender: string;
}

interface Program {
  name: string;
  clientId: string;
  weekId: string;
  type: string;
}

export interface StateInterface {
data: (Program | Client)[];
}



//In component Issue 
const clientsArr = _globalContext.data.filter((el) => el.name === value);

// Error massage on gender Property 
/*Property 'gender' does not exist on type 'Client | Program'.
Property 'gender' does not exist on type 'Program'.*/
console.log(clientsArr[0].gender!)
```

Comment: I am having a similar issue the union type in this case is not solving anything!

Comment: this is driving me crazy most of the answers regarding similar issue are suggesting to user the union between the tow interfaces yet in my case is not doing what is should.

Comment: Have you tried 
```export interface StateInterface {
 data: Array<Client|Program>;
}```?

Comment: you mean to the component ? and cast it there ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate further ? ts knows that the type will be either a client or a program why would import it to the component?

Comment: No, this is another way of declaring an interface element type as an array with multiple member types.

Comment: read more about that on : https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-array

Comment: @mahooresorkh doesn't say that much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typing an Array with a union type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29794014/typing-an-array-with-a-union-type-in-typescript)

Comment: not it is the same solution that I have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243111/discussion-between-mahooresorkh-and-richardson).

Comment: This is correct behavior. At that point typescript has no way to know if that value is a `Client` or a `Program`. What can do is type narrowing with an if statement. You can read more about narrowing here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html

Comment: @coglialoro I mean I could go any but then it's all for nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct behavior. At that point typescript has no way to know if that value is a `Client` or a `Program`. What can do is adding a property that allow you to narrow the type. Here's an example:

```
// Added `human` property just as an example, doesn't have to be a boolean
// You could do something like `type: "client"` and `type: "program"`, 
// it would work aswell
interface Client {
  human: true;
  name: string;
  clientId: string;
  weekId: string;
  gender: string;
}

interface Program {
  human: false;
  name: string;
  clientId: string;
  weekId: string;
  type: string;
}
```

Then when you access it you check for your discriminating property:

```
if(clientsArr[0].human){
  // At this point typescript can be sure that the property exists, so no error
  console.log(clientsArr[0].gender)
}
```

Comment: oddly it works but how can implement this in a clean way I mean why dose it refuse to check if gender is there ? plus could this solution be clean ?

Comment: I don't want to sound rude I mean then you have to do 1.000 type checks to solve this I mean could this be solved by a generic or something similar like casting ?, sure it works but then I have to add keys and values to make ts happy.

Comment: This is a good way to think about this and i'd say it's clean enough. Casting like this: `console.log((clientsArr[0] as Client).gender)` should work aswell but having discriminating type is less prone to errors imo

Comment: The casting looks way better to be honest.

Comment: so bottom line either casting or this type check.... other than that no way.

Comment: But with casting you are telling the compiler that that is a `Client` and the compiler "trusts" you. what happen if clientArr[0] isn't actually a `Client`? with inference the compiler can verify for him self the right type. There can be other way to do this ofc, depends on your program architecture, what you want to do, etc

Comment: I understand the point casting is simply overrating...... but since ts is incapable of understating this at the moment and I don't want to have ifs all over casting,  will help me distinguish this case more

Comment: I thought this could be solved by using some sort of a generic interface if you know what I mean please see this https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-generic-interface that will tell ts ok this array will have either of those values so don't error out maybe it's my ignorance of ts to make me think it will work.

Comment: It's ok to have both types in the array, but when you pick one you can't know which of the 2 it is. Let me make you a dumb example: let's say i've a bag that can contain either stones or potatoes. now i pick the first thing out of the bag and tell you to eat it. will you eat it or check if it's a potato first? :D that's pretty much what's happening here

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this kind of **type** problem by **type casting**:

```
console.log((<Client>clientsArr[0])?.gender);
```

so It guarantees that `clientsArr[0]` type should be `Client`, otherwise `console.log` shows `undefined`.

Also maybe `clientsArr[0]` is `null` and the **question mark** before `.gender` prevents from `Cannot read properties of undefined` error.